# Where to place interface files for plug-ins?

Tags: c#, .net

My application supports plug-ins. There is a project, `PluginUtils`, that contains interfaces and code. This project is included in the application and each plugin.

The problem is that one interface mentions a custom project, but `PluginUtils` causes the custom project to be required in all plug-in types.

```
namespace PluginUtils
{
    public interface IPluginSend
    {
        [Description("Send an email")]
        void SendEmail(string subject, string body, List<string> attachments, List<string> toAddresses);
    }

    public interface IPluginSave
    {
        [Description("Save data")]
        string SaveData(List<MyClass> data, string resultsPath);
    }
}
```

How can I prevent plug-ins that implement `IPluginSend` from having to reference the namespace that contains `MyClass`?

**Edit**

Aarón's answer was key. I had to change some dependencies: `PluginUtils` no longer contains a reference to the namespace of `MyClass`, but `MyClass` now references `PluginUtils`.

Comment: You can't - `MyClass` is part of the contract. Why does the interface mention it if implementors aren't supposed to need it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to invert the dependency. Create an inteface in the PluginUtils project that MyClass could implement (e.g. IMyClass)

```
public class MyClass : IMyClass
```

Then modify your dependant interface to use that interface instead of the concrete class of the external project.

```
public interface IPluginSave
{
    [Description("Save data")]
    string SaveData(List<IMyClass> data, string resultsPath);
}
```

Comment: This answer assumes quite a lot about the nature of the system what `MyClass` is. For all we know the interface should be generic or the dependency on `MyClass` could simply be down to poor composition.